# How to send data to wordpress via post method?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

The wordpress admin backend has a features to create the contact form, which is,

```
the admin first design the form at the panel

there is a short code generated , when the admin put the short code at the post, it automatically create a form
```

However, I wonder are there any way to create another HTML and directly post the data to that page?

Because, no matter it is generate by wordpress or not, it is still a HTML form ,  the code is like this

```
<form action="/test/?preview=true&amp;preview_id=599&amp;preview_nonce=f15a57ac32&amp;post_format=standard#wpcf7-f533-p599-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="533">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.7.2">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f533-p599-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="36db94a80b">
</div>
<p>姓<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-lastname"><input type="text" name="your-lastname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>名<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-firstname"><input type="email" name="your-firstname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>電子郵件<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="text" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>問題<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-question"><input type="text" name="your-question" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>內容<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-details"><textarea name="your-details" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="傳送" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://oshc.zizsoft.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;"><input type="清除" value="Reset"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

If I need a url to post to , is it simply the `domain name + /test/?preview=true&amp;preview_id=599&amp;preview_nonce=f15a57ac32&amp;post_format=standard#wpcf7-f533-p599-o1`? thanks

Comment: As long as you point it to the same location as the original contact form, is should work. only take a look at the original one and see if it uses any tokens for validation of the received post.

Also, why not just try it out and ask for help when / if it does not work ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, as the problem is how to get the pointing location of the form? I tried the link above but it only return to same page instead of posting, are there any way to view the url in chrome developer? thanks.